# Importing SQL Query server-side error

Tags: mysql, sql

I receive this error when I try to upload my SQL data in my new server:

```
SQL query:

-- 
-- Database: `dacwp0_brainhappy_ca`
-- 
`dacwp0_brainhappy_ca` ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax     
to use near '`dacwp0_brainhappy_ca`' at line 4
```

The beginning of my imported .sql file

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version v0.1-int.sec.2.10.0.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
-- 
-- Host: shiku
-- Generation Time: Sep 22, 2016 at 10:48 PM
-- Server version: 5.1.66
-- PHP Version: 5.3.29

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

-- 
-- Database: `dacwp0_brainhappy_ca`
-- 
`dacwp0_brainhappy_ca`;
```

I'm seriously at a loss of what to do.  Any mySQL gurus on here?

Comment: Did you, by chance, edit that phpmyadmin dump file? The last line of your example should say `use dacwp0_brainhappy_ca;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use the said database and in that case you are missing the `use` keyword before database name to use the stated database. It should be

```
use `dacwp0_brainhappy_ca`;
```

See [MySQL Documentation On USE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html) for more information